# sorting a vector os strings c++ visual studio 2010 - error C2784 could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to confirm if this is a bug in visual studio 2010. If yes then can any settings be changed? or how do I solve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> test;

test.push_back("hello"); test.push_back("ABC");

std::sort(test.begin(), test.end());
```

**Well this happened because I did not include the std::string header .**

Comment: What line do you see an error? and I doubt this is a bug because the function is so basic and would have been replicated in many forms by many people

Comment: General rule of thumb: whenever youre about to blame the compiler for something, think again. Its not the compilers fault.

Comment: It's not the compiler - 2010 works for me....

Comment: Not sure where the comment about missing <string> has gone, maybe an answer coming, but - it sounded right. It's a case where you would have been better served posting a complete sample including headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess would be that you forgot to include a header (probably `<string>`). You can end up with some minimal forward declaration (or something like that) from a different header that lets part of the code compile, but other parts break in strange ways leading to misleading error messages.

In a quick test, this compiles with VS 2008 through 2012:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> test;

    test.push_back("hello");
    test.push_back("ABC");

    std::sort(test.begin(), test.end());
}
```

Comment: Ah there it is :) I saw the comment and had a feeling you were right.

Comment: I just figured this out. Thanks, it is indeed perplexing. GCC does not display any errors for the same.

Comment: @EternalLearner: C++ allows any standard header to include any other standard header it wants to, so including `<iostream>` (for example) might indirectly include `<string>` with one compiler, but not with another.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin - you used a very interesting term - "minimal forward declaration". How does that work? Can you point to some resources on the same? or better explain it?

Comment: @EternalLearner: A class declaration like `class X;` will let you do *some* things with `X` (e.g., declare/define pointers and references to `X`) but not others (e.g., defining an actual instance of `X`).

Comment: somehow #include<string> was missing in my code, thank you very much for the help Jerry C.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles fine....

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::vector<std::string> test;

test.push_back("hello");
test.push_back("ABC");

std::sort(test.begin(), test.end());
return 0;
}
```